# Digest auth with Java & Apache client : Always 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, digest-authentication

I'm trying to implement digest auth with an HTTP client, but this does not work at the moment.

Can someone check if this code is correct? For testing purpose I use http://httpbin.org/, but all I get is `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`.

Here is the example code:

```
private static void doDigestAuth() throws ClientProtocolException,
    IOException,
    AuthenticationException,
    MalformedChallengeException
{

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 80, "http");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
        "user", "passwd"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd");

        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate DIGEST scheme object, initialize it and add it to the local
        // auth cache
        DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();

        // Suppose we already know the realm name
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "me@kennethreitz.com");
        // // Suppose we already know the expected nonce value
        // digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", Long.toString(new SecureRandom().nextLong(), 36));
        // qop-value = "auth" | "auth-int" | token
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("qop", "auth");
        authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        // context.setAuthSchemeRegistry(authRegistry);
        context.setAuthCache(authCache);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to target " + target);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                // Header contentCncoding = entity .getContentEncoding();
                String contentString = IOUtils.toString(instream, null);
                System.out.println("ContentString:" + contentString);
                AuthState proxyAuthState = context.getProxyAuthState();
                System.out.println("Proxy auth state: " + proxyAuthState.getState());
                System.out.println("Proxy auth scheme: " + proxyAuthState.getAuthScheme());
                System.out.println("Proxy auth credentials: " + proxyAuthState.getCredentials());
                AuthState targetAuthState = context.getTargetAuthState();
                System.out.println("Target auth state: " + targetAuthState.getState());
                System.out.println("Target auth scheme: " + targetAuthState.getAuthScheme());
                System.out.println("Target auth credentials: " + targetAuthState.getCredentials());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            }
            finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: could you fix this problem?

Comment: Could it be that httpbin requires a cookie and witout cookie set it respond 401?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache HttpClient Digest authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954434/apache-httpclient-digest-authentication)

Answer (score 5):

It was a cookie problem as @heaphach suggested. The wire-log (shown with log category `org.apache.http.wire` set to debug) shows:

`<< "Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value[\r][\n]"`

but the HttpClient never picks this up
and does not use it in the second GET request containing the full "Authorization" header with the digest-response.
As a consequence, the server just ignores the digest response.

After I updated the example code (also known as the [Preemptive DIGEST authentication example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveDigestAuthentication.java))
with the code shown below (copied from the HTTP state management [tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html)), the server responded "200 OK".

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("fake", "fake_value");
cookie.setDomain("httpbin.org");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .build();
```

I also came across a [gist](https://gist.github.com/usamadar/2912088) containing some code to calculate a "nonce"
so you can use 

`digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", calculateNonce());`

and `org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator` no longer shows the error message "missing nonce in challenge".

```
public static synchronized String calculateNonce() {

    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss");
    String fmtDate = f.format(d);
    Random rand = new Random(100000);
    Integer randomInt = rand.nextInt();
    return org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fmtDate + randomInt.toString());
}
```

Comment: There is some change in httpclient v4.5.3 and v4.5.4 regarding this issue.