# Apache http client sample failing for Digest authentication

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, digest-authentication

I am running the sample Apache hc (http client) for digest authentication. I didn't change anything, just using the provided sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 80, "http");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
    try {

        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate DIGEST scheme object, initialize it and add it to the local
        // auth cache
        DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
        // Suppose we already know the realm name
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "me@kennethreitz.com");
        // Suppose we already know the expected nonce value
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", "b2c603bb7c93cfa197945553a1044283");
        authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to target " + target);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

And I am getting: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

If I go direct to http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd in prompts me for user/passwd and then provides the page. So the website is working right.

Any idea what is wrong? I have the latest version of the library.

Fiddler Auth for browser (successful):

> No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
>
> Authorization Header is present: Digest username="user",
>   realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="8ada87344eb5a10bf810bcc211205c24",
>   uri="/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd",
>   response="ad22423e5591d14c90c6fe3cd762e64c",
>   opaque="361645844d957289c4c8f3479f76269f", qop=auth, nc=00000001,
>   cnonce="260d8ddfe64bf32e"

Fiddler Auth for my code (failed):

> No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
>
> Authorization Header is present: Digest username="user",
>   realm="me@kennethreitz.com", nonce="76af6c9c0a1f57ee5f0fcade2a5f758c",
>   uri="http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd",
>   response="745686e3f38ab40ce5907d41f91823e6", qop=auth, nc=00000001,
>   cnonce="634b618d5c8ac9af", algorithm=MD5,
>   opaque="fe84ce11c48a7b258490600800e5e6df"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache HttpClient Digest authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954434/apache-httpclient-digest-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

This code `digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "some realm")` should have some change.To replace  `"some realm"` by your server realm.Please look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954434/apache-httpclient-digest-authentication)

Comment: How can I determine the realm programatically? This code is for a library that will run on many computers connecting to many servers. So I can't hard code it.

Comment: See here to set realm programatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028003/apache-httpclient-digestauth-doesnt-forward-opaque-value-from-challenge/53028597#53028597

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. You have to set a cookie too. [Thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291842/digest-auth-with-java-apache-client-always-401-unauthorized/33558238#33558238) for the help. The below code works - but only if you are **not** using Fiddler.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("fake", "fake_value");
        cookie.setDomain("httpbin.org");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291842/digest-auth-with-java-apache-client-always-401-unauthorized

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 80, "http");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
//              .setProxy(new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888))
                .build();
        try {

            // Create AuthCache instance
            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            // Generate DIGEST scheme object, initialize it and add it to the local
            // auth cache
            DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
            // Suppose we already know the realm name
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "me@kennethreitz.com");
            // Suppose we already know the expected nonce value
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", calculateNonce());
            authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

            // Add AuthCache to the execution context
            HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd");

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to target " + target);
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
                try {
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                } finally {
                    response.close();
                }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized String calculateNonce() {

        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss");
        String fmtDate = f.format(d);
        Random rand = new Random(100000);
        Integer randomInt = rand.nextInt();
        return org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fmtDate + randomInt.toString());
    }
```