# problem with the collectors.tomap and the HeaderEelement's getValue and getNmae

Tags: java, header, httpclient, collectors

when trying to reproduce the following code the compiler is not happy with the expression in the picture

[Apache HTTPClient DigestAuth doesn't forward "opaque" value from Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028003/apache-httpclient-digestauth-doesnt-forward-opaque-value-from-challenge/53028597#53028597)

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Also, give detailed steps to reproduce, e.g. used libraries, versions, and your code: Post a [mcve] rather than incomplete screenshots

Comment: this should work like a charm : `Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(httpResponse.getHeaders("")[0].getElements()).collect(Collectors.toMap(HeaderElement::getName, HeaderElement::getValue));`

Comment: Like @CodeScale, I do not get any compile error for exact same code like yours Mehdi.  It is Apache HttpClient-4.5.jar, and jdk 11.

Comment: I have jdk 1.8.241

Comment: still the same even after moving ti JDK 11

Comment: in fact it's a maven project and the dependencies are all in the pom file, do you think it's a problem with maven or eclipse, may be i need to add all the dependencies manually because i tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the project compliance, because eclipse is by default compliant with J2SE-1.5, i don't know why it doesn't occur at the first time but when moving the mouse upon the getValue the compiler proposed me to change the compliance to 1.8, i did and problem solved.