# Apache HTTPClient DigestAuth authorization doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, digest-authentication

At the first access to the server, my authorization is successful (although this is not correct). I don’t understand why digest authorization in this code occurs so early.
I'm using the following solution:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.testng.Assert;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SOAPClientApache {


    private static final String URL = "https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd";


    private static final String PASSWORD = "passwd";    //passwd

    private static final String USER = "user";          //user

    public void run() throws Exception {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(httpget.getURI().getHost(), 443, "https");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USER, PASSWORD);
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
                credentials);

         CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        //SSL solution
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient
                = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();  

        try {

            DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();

            digestAuth.overrideParamter("qop", "auth");
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nc", "0");
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("cnonce", DigestScheme.createCnonce());

            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

            HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

            CloseableHttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);

            //Массив headers (для тестов)
            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            for (Header header : headers) {
                System.out.println(header);
            }
            System.out.println();

            Map<String, String> wwwAuth = Arrays
                    .stream(response.getHeaders("WWW-Authenticate")[0]
                            .getElements())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(HeaderElement::getName,
                            HeaderElement::getValue));

            //Выведем наш массивчик чтобы лицезреть
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> pair : wwwAuth.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            }

            // the first call ALWAYS fails with a 401
            Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 401);

            digestAuth.overrideParamter("opaque", wwwAuth.get("opaque"));
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", wwwAuth.get("nonce"));
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", wwwAuth.get("Digest realm"));

            Header authenticate = digestAuth.authenticate(credentials, httpget, localContext);
            httpget.addHeader(authenticate);


            response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);

            // the 2nd call is the real deal
            Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 200);

            System.out.println(IOUtils
                    .toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"));


        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When the program reaches this step:

```
 Map<String, String> wwwAuth = Arrays
                        .stream(response.getHeaders("WWW-Authenticate")[0]
                                .getElements())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(HeaderElement::getName,
                                HeaderElement::getValue));
```

then "response: HTTP / 1.1 200 OK" and the program exits to exception

Comment: why are you using basic and digest authentication together?

Comment: @pero_hero, it was originally intended to use only digest-authorization. 
I did following the example from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028003/apache-httpclient-digestauth-doesnt-forward-opaque-value-from-challenge/53028597#53028597