# Digest authentication using apache httpclient

Tags: java, apache, authentication

I am implementing a simple (not preemptive, not through proxy) digest authentication using apache HttpClient5. Documentation is quite sparse, but it should be fairly simple.

However, I keep getting 401 as a response, and I am not clear on how I can establish if this is because of implementation mistakes on my part, or if the 401 is genuine. The used credentials are definately correct, I checked.

So my questions are:

1. Is this code basically correct or am I missing something (do I have to process the challenge myself for example. I am assuming the httpClient does this for me).
2. If processing the challenge fails because it is done incorrectly, should I not get some more information in the log other than a 401.
3. digest{} authentication error: missing realm: Is this normal in the first fase of the authencation process, or should I preemptively provide the realm? I am assuming the httpClient gets this from the challenge from the server and can provide it in the second call. On the other hand it is marked as 'severe'...

.. this is the code segment ..
.. I cleaned up the code a bit so it only represents the lines for the digest authentication. 
.. maybe the closeconnection statement wreaks havock?

```
            HttpRequestBase request = request = new HttpGet(params.getRequestUrl());
            // .....
            // then setting requestconfig, headers, body, contenttype etc.
            // .....
            HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            // set authentication (just a POJO with a username and a password)
            final HttpBasicAuthentication authentication = params.getAuthentication();
            URI uri = request.getURI();
            String host = uri.getHost();
            int port = uri.getPort();
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host,port,scheme);

            char[] password = authentication.getPassword().toCharArray();
            final org.apache.hc.client5.http.auth.Credentials creds = new org.apache.hc.client5.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials(authentication.getUsername(), password);
            BasicCredentialsProvider cP = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); 
                cP.setCredentials(org.apache.hc.client5.http.auth.AuthScope.ANY, creds); 
            localContext.setCredentialsProvider(cP);

            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
            authCache.put(target, digestScheme);    
            localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

            // Tell the HTTP server that we will close the connection after the response
            request.addHeader("Connection", "close");

            // http response
            final HttpServiceResponse response = new HttpServiceResponse();

            // Execute the method.
            CloseableHttpResponse closeableResponse = httpClient5.execute(request, localContext);
```

Logging...

```
... sorry... I had to remove the logging. because of security conserns.
```

Comment: not closing the connection does not make much difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache HttpClient Digest authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954434/apache-httpclient-digest-authentication)